# RxJava-Jdbc 0.5.7: How to obtain last insert id?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, rx-java

**Using Code sample from here:**
https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc

**How do I get last insert id from mysql?**

```
database.update("insert into person(name,sex,age,dob) values(?,?,?,?)")
.parameters(person.getName(), person.isMale(), person.getAge(), person.getDob());
```

Prefers to use the NonBlocking Reactive Pattern

**In JDBC I could so something like this:**

```
Statement stmt = db.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
numero = stmt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()){
    risultato=rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

```
Observable<Integer> key = db.update("insert into note(text) values(?)")
  .parameter("hello", "there")
  .returnGeneratedKeys()
  .getAs(Integer.class);
```

So, if you want the concrete Integer value instead of the Observable you could do:

```
Observable<Integer> key = db.update("insert into note(text) values(?)")
  .parameter("hello", "there")
  .returnGeneratedKeys()
  .getAs(Integer.class);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two code chunks.